# Codename One's MediaPlayer works in Simulator but on Android

Tags: codenameone

I want to have a simple form that shows a video from a public URL. So I found out the `MediaPlayer` controller and I copied the example from the [docs](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/components/MediaPlayer.html)

```
final Form hi = new Form("MediaPlayer", new BorderLayout());
hi.setToolbar(new Toolbar());
Style s = UIManager.getInstance().getComponentStyle("Title");
FontImage icon = 
FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_VIDEO_LIBRARY, s);

hi.getToolbar().addCommandToRightBar(new Command("", icon) {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        Display.getInstance().openGallery((e) -> {
            if(e != null && e.getSource() != null) {
                String file = (String)e.getSource();
                try {
                    Media video = MediaManager.createMedia(file, true);
                    hi.removeAll();
                    hi.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, new MediaPlayer(video));
                    hi.revalidate();
                } catch(IOException err) {
                    Log.e(err);
                } 
            }
        }, Display.GALLERY_VIDEO);
    }
});
hi.show();
```

It worked flawlessly in the simulator, the button appears and when I select a video file the component appears.

But when testing it on actual Android device, after I select the video nothing happens. I wonder if I missed some configuration. I am looking for the simplest possible way to run videos on Codename One for Android.

EDIT: It looks like the event listener in `Display#openGallery` is not being called.

Comment: I just tried this exact code on my device and it worked perfectly. Notice that the video doesn't start playing automatically, you need to tap it to play. If this is still not working which Android device/OS version (I used One Plus 6 running Oreo). Also connect a cable and look at the device output to see if there was an exception